# mysql problem, check to see if an item exist

Tags: php, mysql

```
$gt = 'andrew';

mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
mysql_select_db('database');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT gamertag FROM register WHERE gamertag = '".$gt."'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $gt = $row['gamertag'];
}

if($gt = 'andrew') {
    echo 'This gamertag has previously been registered!';
}
```

Comment: -1 for not bothering to elaborate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HUGE problem:

```
if($gt = 'andrew'){
echo 'This gamertag has previously been registered!';
}
```

will always evaluate to true .... replace `$gt = 'andrew'`  with `$gt == 'andrew'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$gt = 'andrew';

mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
mysql_select_db('database');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT gamertag FROM register WHERE gamertag = '".$gt."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo 'This gamertag has previously been registered!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($gt = 'andrew'){
echo 'This gamertag has previously been registered!';
}
```

You need a == to test for equality. Change the above to:

```
if($gt == 'andrew'){
echo 'This gamertag has previously been registered!';
}
```

You also probably have a SQL injection vulnerability. You should have the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$gt`

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $gt = $row['gamertag'];
}

if($gt = 'andrew'){
echo 'This gamertag has previously been registered!';
}
```

This code seems unnecessary. Seems you could just as easily do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo 'This gamertag has previously been registered!';
}
```

As soon as you have a result, you know the tag has already been used. The code inside the while loop won't execute if you don't have a result, i.e. the name hasn't already been used.

Comment: You just copy-pasted the mistake.

Comment: I think his point was that the OP could have done it differently, hence blind copy+paste is acceptable.

Comment: We're programmers. Not even open-eyed copy/paste is acceptable. It's a bad habit and creates a considerable amount of bugs.

Comment: My point is the wrong code should be excluded completely. How is that bad?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is already checking whether the item exists. From this, we can tell that if any rows are returned from the query, the item exists. So your code can be as simple as:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'This gamertag exists!'
}
```